# ¿Evento para "ratón cerca de elemento" en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, eventos

Con JavaScript/jQuery puedo crear eventos para cuando el ratón entra o sale de un elemento usando `mouseenter` y `mouseleave`. Por ejemplo:

```js
var img = document.querySelector("img");

img.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
  console.log("Estoy sobre la imagen");
});

img.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
  console.log("Ya no estoy sobre la imagen");
});
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/200" />
```

Eso hará que se ejecuten acciones (mostrar mensajes por la consola) cuando el ratón entre o salga de la imagen. Ahora mi pregunta es: **¿existe algún evento que en lugar de lanzarse cuando el ratón entre en la imagen, se dispare cuando el ratón esté en la proximidad de la imagen?**

Por ejemplo, si tengo una imagen (aunque potencialmente podría ser cualquier elemento como un `div` o un `thead`) junto a un texto, y el ratón se acerca a menos de 30px del borde de la misma, se ejecute una acción en JavaScript. Este gráfico muestra más o menos lo que quiero - algo debería ocurrir si el ratón entra dentro del área que hay alrededor de la imagen (resaltada en rojo sólo como ejemplo, es un área "imaginaria"):

[image: imagen junto a texto y área de acción]

Si no existe, ¿cómo se podría simular ese evento con JavaScript o jQuery?

Comment: A mi se me ocurre que pongas un div rodeando el botón de n píxeles y a ese div le añadas eventos de mouseenter y mouseleave

Comment: Solo por curiosidad, ¿cómo defines la proximidad? me explico: ¿cuántos píxeles antes de "llegar al elemento?

Comment: Podés usar mousemove() de jQuery sobre un div mas grande como dijeron mas arriba, o probablemente sobre document mismo. Y después vos tenes que manejar la posición y espacio de cada elemento y definir la función de distancia desde el punto de click para determinar si estás cerca.

Comment: @Shaz pon que sean 30px o menos del borde del elemento. Voy a editar la pregunta para añadir una imagen que lo explique mejor.

Comment: [Esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7920345/3045491) te permite seleccionar un radio de pixeles alrededor de una imagen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**INTRODUCCION:**

---

Para hacerlo con javascript puro haremos lo siguiente:
Crearemos una funcion para que al accionarse un evento del mouse (en este caso onmousemove) este compruebe la distancia que hay entre el mouse y el objeto 
(ya definidos ambos) y en el caso de cumplirse haria la accion que deseemos.

**PARAMETROS NECESARIOS:**

---

Por lo tanto necesitariamos tres parametros:

```
objeto = el elemento HTML que accionara la funcion.
distancia = cantidad que deseamos entre el mouse y el objeto.
evento = el evento que accionara la comprobacion de la distancia.
```

**METODOS Y FUNCIONES A USAR:**

---

Ya tenemos listo los parametros, lo siguiente seria obtener los cuatro lados del objeto, esto lo haremos con `offset`, el cual permite obtener la posicion en pixeles de la parte margen o limite del elemento.

Tendremos dos posibildiades `offsetLeft` y `offsetTop`.

Faltaria definir la parte inferior y derecha del objeto, por lo que usaremos:

`width` para obtener el ancho (siendo este usando para calcular el margen derecho)
`height` la altura (para calcular el punto mas bajo)

**GRAFICO PARA ENTENDER MEJOR:**

---

Pensemos antes en esta gráfica de los ejes X/Y:

```
        100
         50
-100 -50 0 50 100
         -50
         -100
```

Con la cual nos guiaremos en los cálculos para el limite del objeto.

**DEFINIENDO LOS LIMITES:**

---

*IZQUIERDO:*

---

Ahora comenzamos entonces a crear los lados del objeto:

```
var izquierdo= objeto.offsetLeft - distancia;
```

Obtenemos el valor del margen izquierdo y luego restamos la distancia para crear el limite que queremos con el objeto respecto al lado izquierdo, si lo restamos la posicion limite se correra hacia la izquierda.

*SUPERIOR:*

---

```
var superior= objeto.offsetTop - distancia;
```

Obtenemos el valor del margen superior y luego restamos la distancia para crear el limite que queremos con el objeto respecto a su altura.

*DERECHO:*

---

Ahora vayamos con los lados calculados:

Para el derecho usaremos la posición del margen izquierdo y luego sumaremos la anchura del objeto, esto daría como resultado el margen derecho, y luego sumamos la distancia que queremos de limite.

```
var derecho = izquierdo + objeto.witdh() + (2*distancia);
```

Se usa la multiplicacion, porque el limite con la distancia sin multiplicar quedaria justo en el margen del objeto.

*INFERIOR:*

---

Para el inferior usaremos la posición del margen superior y luego sumaremos la altura del objeto, esto daría como resultado el margen derecho, y luego sumamos la distancia que queremos de limite.

```
var inferior = superior + objeto.heigth() + (2*distancia);
```

Se usa la multiplicación, porque el limite con la distancia sin multiplicar quedaria justo en el margen del objeto.

**LIMITES FINALES:**

---

Quedando nuestros limites asi:

```
var izquierdo = objeto.offsetLeft - distancia;
var superior = objeto.offsetTop - distancia;
var derecho =  izquierdo + objeto.width() + (2*distancia);
var bottom = superior + objeto.height() + (2*distancia);
```

**POSICION DEL MOUSE:**

---

A continuacion debemos obtener la posicion (coordenadas) del mouse tanto para el eje X como el Y.

Para esto usaremos `pageX` y `pageY`, los cuales reaccionaran con el evento (onmousemove)

Guardemos así:

```
var X= evento.pageX;
var Y= evento.pageY;
```

Donde evento sera:

```
document.onmousemove
```

**COMPROBANDO DISTANCIA:**

---

Veremos como comprobar la posicion del mouse en relacion al objeto y el plano cartesiano, con lo cual debe cumplirse que:

- La posicion X sea mayor que el margen izquierdo
- La posicion X sea menor que el margen derecho
- La posicion Y sea mayor que el margen superior
- La posicion Y sea menor que el margen inferior.

Ahora usaremos un return para saber si se cumple o no, de la siguiente manera:

```
return ( X > izquierdo && X < derecho && Y > superior && Y < inferior );
```

**FUNCION FINAL:**

---

```
function cercano( objeto, distancia, evento ) {

    var izquierdo = objeto.offsetLeft - distancia;
    var superior = objeto.offsetTop - distancia;
    var derecho = izquierdo + objeto.width() + (2*distancia);
    var inferior = superior + objeto.height() + (2*distancia);
    var X = evento.pageX;
    var Y = evento.pageY;

    return ( X > izquierdo && X < derecho && Y > superior && Y < inferior );

};
```

**ACCIONAR EVENTO DEL MOUSE:**

---

Declararemos dentro de nuestro archivo JavaScript la función de calcular cuando ocurra el evento `onmousemove`, quedado así:

```
<img id="imagen" src="http://placehold.it/200" />

<script>
document.onmousemove = function () {
    var objeto = document.getElementById("imagen");
    var evento = document.event;
    if (cercano(objeto, 20, evento)) {
        console.log("estoy Cerca");
    }
    }
```

**CODIGO FINAL:**

```
    <img id="imagen" src="http://placehold.it/200" />

    document.onmousemove = function () {
    var objeto = document.getElementById("imagen");
    var evento = document.event;
    if (cercano(objeto, 20, evento)) {
        console.log("estoy Cerca");
    }

     function cercano( objeto, distancia, evento ) {

        var izquierdo = objeto.offsetLeft - distancia;
        var superior = objeto.offsetTop - distancia;
        var derecho = izquierdo + objeto.width + (2*distancia);
        var inferior = superior + objeto.height + (2*distancia);
        var X = evento.pageX;
        var Y = evento.pageY;

        return ( X > izquierdo && X < derecho && Y > superior && Y < inferior );

    }
}
```

Con esto estaria listo nuestra funcion

**AGREGEMOS ESTILO PARA VERLO MEJOR:**

---

```js
function cercano(objeto, distancia, evento) {
        var izquierdo = objeto.offsetLeft - distancia;
        var superior = objeto.offsetTop - distancia;
        var derecho = izquierdo + objeto.width + (2*distancia);
        var inferior = superior + objeto.height + (2*distancia);
        var X = evento.pageX;
        var Y = evento.pageY;
        return (X > izquierdo && X < derecho && Y > superior && Y < inferior);

    }
    document.onmousemove = function () {
    var objeto = document.getElementById("imagen");
    var evento = window.event;
    if (cercano(objeto, 30, evento)) {
        alert("estoy Cerca");
    }
}
```

```html
<img id="imagen" src="http://placehold.it/200"/>
```

**CREDITOS:**

---

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911604/function-for-mouse-near-an-element-in-jquery
```

Comment: Esto no termina de funcionar. Parece que va bien cuando me acerco por arriba o por la izquierda, pero si me acerco por la derecha o por abajo, falla y no dice lo de "estoy Cerca" hasta que está justo encima

Comment: Entonces agregemos esto: (2* distancia),puede ser que al calcular el ancho y la parte de abajo se deba aumentar el tamaño de la distancia limite, modificare el codigo

Comment: Cuando sumamos el limite con la dsitancia normal, queda en el limite, por eso multiplicaremos por 2, para que salga el limite

Answer (score 9):

Acabo de improvisar el código por lo que puede tener errores, pero creo que algo así podría ser la solución.

Calculando la distancia entre el ratón y el objeto para decidir si el ratón está sobre la imagen, cerca o lejos de ésta.

La variable `distanciaMinima` establece la distancia mínima según la cual se considera que el ratón se encuentra cerca de la imagen.

```js
$(function(){

  var $img = $('.image');
  var $container = $(".container");
  

  var estaEncima;
  var estaCerca;
  var distanciaMinima = 30;
  
  $container.on('mousemove', function(e){
    var distance = calculateDistance(e.pageX, e.pageY, $img);
    if (distance.x === 0 && distance.y === 0){
      // Está encima
      if (estaEncima === false){
        console.log('Estoy sobre la imagen');
        estaEncima = true;
        estaCerca = true;
      }
      return;
    }
    // No está encima
    if (estaEncima === true) {
      console.log('Ya no estoy sobre la imagen');
    }
    estaEncima = false;
      
    var distanciaCalculada = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(distance.x, 2) + Math.pow(distance.y, 2)));
    var cerca = distanciaCalculada < distanciaMinima;
    if (cerca !== estaCerca){
      estaCerca = cerca;
      console.log(estaCerca
        ? 'Estoy cerca de la imagen'
        : 'Ya no estoy cerca de la imagen');
    }
      
  });
  
  function calculateDistance(x, y, elem){
    var elemX = elem.offset().left;
    var elemY = elem.offset().top;
    var elemX2 = elemX + elem.width();
    var elemY2 = elemY + elem.height();
    var distanceX = x < elemX
      ? elemX - x
      : (x > elemX2 ? x - elemX2 : 0);
    var distanceY = y < elemY
      ? elemY - y
      : (y > elemY2 ? y - elemY2 : 0);
    return { x: distanceX, y: distanceY };
  }

});
```

```css
.container{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/200" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

puedes agregar un elemento div y con la propiedad padding especificas el rango de aproximacion a la imagen, y agregas el evento mouseenter, seria algo asi:

```js
var img = document.querySelector("img");
var cont = document.getElementById("cont");

 cont.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
  console.log("Estoy cerca de la imagen");
});

img.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
  console.log("Estoy sobre la imagen");
});

   img.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
  console.log("Ya no estoy sobre la imagen");
});
```

```html
<div id='cont' style='background-color:red;padding:10%;height:200px;width:200px;' >
<img src="http://placehold.it/200" />
</div>
```

Comment: Esta solución es interesante, pero le veo un problema: el modo en el que se está poniendo el contenedor me afectaría al resto de elementos (que serían "empujados" lejos de la imagen) y no se podría usar en otros elementos (por ejemplo una fila `tr`).

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro , siendo sincero, no me manejo mucho con css y estilos, pero lo que se podria hacer para no "empujar" otros objetos, es usar la propiedad "z-index", esta propiedad se podria aplicar tanto al div de "acercamiento", como a los otros elementos.

link de referencia : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Answer (score 2):

Solo tienes que agregar un div con un tamaño especifico y agregarle un padding al div:

Ejemplo si tu imagen es de 100x100 px, tu div sera de 200x200 px y así agregas un padding de 100px al div y tienes ese rango para lo que quieres hacer, el evento se lo agregas al div y seria todo.

```
<style>
  div{
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   padding: 100px; //(si es necesario)
  }
  img{
   width: 100px;
  }
</style>
<div 'aqui-el-evento'>
 <img src="x">
</div>
```

Y con esto debería funcionar sin, no probe el código pero debería funcionar adaptado a tus necesidades.